# Brushless DC motor sometimes running backwards

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor

I'm working on a motor control system I've inherited.  It's custom designed but I have access to all the schematics and source code.  The way the code is written the motor controller responds to commands over the serial port to go X hall counts forwards or reverse.  In a test we ran the other day we had the motor running in hall count steps equivalent to .2 degrees of rotation of our mechanism; thus it would step .2 degrees, then be instructed again to step .2 degrees etc.  It was rotating fine in the chosen direction, but then went into a state where it free ran at full speed in the other direction until we cut the power.

Any clues on how to debug this?  My first step is going be recording the hall count and direction commands sent from the master to see if a bad command is telling it to go in reverse.  If the commands look good then what else should I look at?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Did it work again after you restored power?  If so, Olin's bug idea is likely.  If not, it's probably a failure of the encoder, encoder circuitry, or wiring.

Comment: what kind of control ? sensorless BEMF or with IRC encoders  or with magnetic field HAL  sensors?  SW bug is always an option but I stumped on one particular motor (very high speed up to 100000 rpm) which sometimes starts in the opposite direction with same moment and speed as in the intended direction due to fact its too fast and sometimes starting moment along with magnetic interference creates a resonance skipping 1 phase (pole) along the electrical round creating a specific noisy sound. The issue can be solved by changing starting current and or speeds ...

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a firmware bug.  Other than that there is little that can be answered from the information you have given.

One thing to keep in mind is that .2 deg motor rotation may not be the same as .2 deg advance thru the drive phases.  Motors often have multiple complete cycles thru the drive coils for one physical rotation.  Sometimes this ratio is referred to as the number of "poles" the motor has.  For example, if it is a 4 pole motor, then .2 deg shaft rotation would be .8 deg advance thru the one complete drive cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are wondering why the system worked fine with the old motor however and just changing to a different motor has exposed the bug.  Exactly the same software works fine with the old motor.

Comment: Maybe the phase angles of the hall sensors is a bit different with the new motor, or possibly they are not wired in the same sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of that, if that is the case I still can't think why it would suddenly run seemingly out of control in the reverse direction after a period of time.

Comment: As I recall I previously asked questions about how "identical" old and new motors were and suggested some tests or observations to be sure of identicality. I don't know if this was followed or is or was relevant but it sounds so.

Comment: @fred: What Russell said, but also consider that there could have been a lurking firmware bug all along, and something slightly different with the new motor is triggering it.  You can drive each of the phases manually and see where their center positions are.  Then do the same with the Hall sensors and see how they match up.  Remember, the vast majority of software, and even more so for microcontroller firmware, is very poorly written.